# Does django-celery-beat deal with multiple instances of django processes created by web-servers

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery-beat

I have a fairly complex periodic-tasks that needs to be offloaded from django context. django-celery-beat looks promising. While I was going through [celery-beat docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes), I found this:

> You have to ensure only a single scheduler is running for a schedule at a time, otherwise you’d end up with duplicate tasks. Using a centralized approach means the schedule doesn’t have to be synchronized, and the service can operate without using locks.

A typical production deployment will spawn a pool of worker-processes each running a django instance. Will that result in creation of multiple scheduler processes as well? Do I need to have some synchronisation logic?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It does not.

You can dig into the issues page on their github repo for confirmation.  I think it's weird that the documentation doesn't call this out, but I suppose you have to assume that's how all celery beats work unless they specify otherwise.

In theory, you could build your own synchronization, but it will probably be a better experience to use a different scheduler that has that functionality built in, like Heroku's redbeat: https://blog.heroku.com/redbeat-celery-beat-scheduler.

Comment: I think I totally misunderstood how the scheduler is started. ``Django`` on its own won't touch the celery things. We start scheduler with something like this ``celery -A proj beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`` unless we execute this command twice there are no two schedulers running for same schedule

Comment: Haha Infact I had to write my own custom scheduler as I needed an ability to declare task dependencies among celery tasks. But it is not in full fledge use as I am building the other components of my system. [Here](https://github.com/m0hithreddy/djag-scheduler) if you are interested